# ros_control with open loop system

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to ask one question and hopefully someone will help me with that. I am not so professional.

Is it possible to use ros_control pkg with open loop system. I mean I have a stepper motor without encoder, so I don't have the position of the motor, I calculating it just by summarize every time my command in pulses to the motor.

Because, as far as I understand the ros_control pkg require the close loop system to control it with PID.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345676/ros_control-with-open-loop-system/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2020-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Because, as far as I understand the ros_control pkg require the close loop system to control it with PID.

This is actually not entirely correct.

*Some* controllers in `ros_controllers` are closed-loop, but there are quite a few which are actually open-loop (so called *command forwarding* controllers). For instance: all controllers which take a position setpoint and output a position (ie: `position_controllers/JointPositionController`) are completely open-loop (see [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/2d5ba0744a1eec7c9720ef3df6e8b571466d8f90/position_controllers/include/position_controllers/joint_position_controller.h#L58-L59)).

> Is it possible to use ros_control pkg with open loop system.

So: yes. This would be possible.

> I mean I have a stepper motor without encoder, so I don't have the position of the motor, I calculating it just by summarize every time my command in pulses to the motor.

If you implement a `hardware_interface` that simply copies `command -> current_state` (perhaps with a small delay) then none of the controllers will ever notice this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0